# How to find out when a download has completed in mobile when using PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am using a PHP header for downloading a JAR file and [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) files in mobile. I can download the files successfully, but I want to show a popup when the download reaches 100%. How do I achieve this?

Is there any callback method for the download complete event?

```
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Length: '.$stat['size']);
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
readfile($path_to_file);
```

Comment: i dont think there is, you should call your function right when the download start.

Comment: After `readfile`, update a database or some other data store with a piece of data showing the download for that user has completed. In your jQuery, poll some URL that checks for this data existing in the database. When it's there, the download is finished, so your jQuery callback can display the popup.

Answer (score 0):

There's no 'download finished' event. But you can use a workaround:

http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx

See [Detect when browser receives file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download?lq=1)